# How come this query shows the same address for non-authoritative answers and authoritative answers?

Tags: networking, dns, query, nameserver, nslookup

So, if i query slash16.org:

```
nslookup -type=ns slash16.org

Non-authoritative answer:
slash16.org nameserver = ns-686.awsdns-21.net.
slash16.org nameserver = ns-1989.awsdns-56.co.uk.
slash16.org nameserver = ns-144.awsdns-18.com.
slash16.org nameserver = ns-1236.awsdns-26.org.

Authoritative answers can be found from:
ns-1236.awsdns-26.org   internet address = 205.251.196.212
```

Why ns-1236.awsdns-26.org has both authoritative and non-authoritative answers?

Comment: Can you post `/etc/resolv.conf`? It is likely that the answer may be found there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the DNS server finds a record that the client needs to query in its own zone file, it will return an authoritative response. For example, if the client wants to find the IP address of the srv1.contoso.com host, it will look up the "A record" of the host on the contoso.com DC (that is, the DNS server). If we find it, we will return the recorded content to the client through DNS reply. This is an authoritative response. Of course, the actual query method is more complicated than I said.

In addition, if the Dns server has recently been queried for the host (and possibly other clients have also looked up) records, it will find the record answering client in the cache.

If the DC server cannot find the A record of the srv1.contoso.com host, it will return a (RecordNotFound) response - also an authoritative response.

If the server receiving the DNS query request is not the DC (Dns server) of contoso.com, then the following method is used to process the request:
First, query other Dns servers until they find it, and then the server will return the found content to the client --- Non-authoritative response.
Second, recommend the client to the upper Dns server to find. --- Non-authoritative response.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So a server that is able to give an authoritative answer will always be able to give both a non-authoritative answer(because the record MIGHT not be in its zone file and in this case it will query other DNS servers), and it will always show up in both answers. Is that right?

Comment: I'm sorry to reply you so late. Yes, your understanding is right.

Comment: I don't follow this.  If server queried is authoritative, that means that it has a copy of the zone file, and therefore the answer is always authoritative.  If it doesn't have the zone file, then it isn't authoritative. If it is authoritative, then it would never query another server, because there isn't one to query that is more authoritative than itself.  I am not sure this answers the question.